# Get week number from a list of dates in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to get listed the corresponding week number from the dates that result from this query.

```
select Date,Time,EndDate,EndTime
FROM Test
WHERE (StartDate >= '01.01.2019')
ORDER BY StartDate
```

Basically, I want adding to the end column the week number from this query.
I can't edit the database in anyway, I just want to extract the week number from the dates and have it as a column at the end of my results.

Sample data below:

[image: Results]

Comment: Sorry should have elaborated, I'm just using SSMS on a sql express server

Comment: Sample data would be very helpful here.

Comment: Have you looked at the [DATEPART()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datepart-transact-sql) options?

Comment: Week numbering isn't the same everywhere, so please tell where are you to see the numbering scheme needed

Comment: Hi, I'm in the UK

Comment: So use `iso_week` instead of week (first days of Jan of new year can belong to 52nd or 53rd week of previous year and also last day of Dec can belong to first week of new year). Avoid using 'simple' `week` function as it will return you 'american' week. Also remember to `set datefirst 1`

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I usually use the `ROW_NUMBER()` function to accomplish this:

```
select 
    Date,
    Time,
    EndDate,
    EndTime, 
    ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by year(EndDate), datepart(weekday, EndDate) order by EndDate) as WeekNumInYear
FROM Test
WHERE 
    (StartDate >= '01.01.2019')
ORDER BY 
    StartDate
```

Comment: The benefit to using ROW_NUMBER is that you can adapt the query to work off a table of fiscal periods instead of just calendar dates.

Comment: This is incorrect. You need to use datepart(week,enddate) for this. [See the demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=8561e31f1921daf4ed6f3c20b49a5b5a)

Comment: It's not incorrect - the "partition by year" ensures that the weeks are numbered properly within each year, if you have a calendar table of more than one year.  Using row_number() with "datepart(weekday, EndDate)" works on SQL Server just fine.  I was just offering a different way that can also be easily adapted to fiscal years that don't exactly align with calendar years (4-4-5).

Comment: Well, your first row needs to be a Sunday, otherwise the grouping is off... no? See the demo i linked.

Answer (score 2):

Just use datepart function:

```
select datepart(week, Date), Date,Time,EndDate,EndTime
FROM Test
WHERE (StartDate >= '01.01.2019')
ORDER BY StartDate
```

Answer (score 1):

use `datepart(wk,date)`:-

```
select Date,Time,EndDate,EndTime,datepart(wk,date)as week
FROM Test
WHERE (StartDate >= '01.01.2019')
ORDER BY StartDate
```

Comment: [I'd make a habit of not using shorthand with date/time functions](https://sqlblog.org/2011/09/20/bad-habits-to-kick-using-shorthand-with-date-time-operations).  I think it'll prove better for you in the long run :)

Answer (score 1):

In UK ISO week is used: the first year's week is the one including 4th of Jan.

So:

```
set datefirst 1 --this sets Monday as first day of the week 
set dateformat dmy -- nosrmal date format
select Date,Time,EndDate,EndTime,datepart(iso_week,date)as week
FROM Test
WHERE (StartDate >= '01.01.2019')
ORDER BY StartDate
```

Remember that first days of Jan may be 52nd or 53rd week of previous year and also last day of December may belong to first week of new year.

the check to see the week number and postponed to the yeear it belongs to is the following:

```
week_and_year = case when datepart(iso_week,date)>=52 and month(date)=1 
                           then concat(year(date)-1,datepart(iso_week,date))
                      when datepart(iso_week,date)=1 and month(date)=12
                           then concat(year(date)+1,datepart(iso_week,date))
                      else concat(year(date),datepart(iso_week,date))
                      end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DATEPART(WEEK,GETDATE()-14)
SELECT DATEPART(WEEK,GETDATE()-7)
SELECT DATEPART(WEEK,GETDATE())
SELECT DATEPART(WEEK,GETDATE()+7)
SELECT DATEPART(WEEK,GETDATE()+14)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use Vertica, try this

```
 date_part('ISODOW', date)
```

'ISODOW' - The ISO day of the week, an integer between 1 and 7 where Monday is 1.